# MYSQL does not start via XAMPP Control Panel

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I open XAMPP and click start MySQL button and it gives me an error. I had started it just before, but now it isn't working.

[XAMPP Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x679V.png)

```
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 2555037; transaction id 2832
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220615  1:19:48
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2022-06-15  1:19:48 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: Try right clicking on the icon to start XAMPP and choose "Run as Administrator"

Comment: it doesn't work. i get the same error message